# Rotate elements in a vector and how to return a vector

Tags: c++, vector

c++ newbie here. So for an assignment I have to rotate all the elements in a vector to the left one. So, for instance, the elements {1,2,3} should rotate to {2,3,1}.

I'm researching how to do it, and I saw the rotate() function, but I don't think that will work given my code. And then I saw a for loop that could do it, but I'm not sure how to translate that into a return statement. (i tried to adjust it and failed)

This is what I have so far, but it is very wrong (i haven't gotten a single result that hasn't ended in an error yet)

Edit: The vector size I have to deal with is just three, so it doesn't need to account for any sized vector

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> rotate(const vector<int>& v)
{
   // PUT CODE BELOW THIS LINE. DON'T CHANGE ANYTHING ABOVE.
   vector<int> result;
   int size = 3;
   for (auto i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i)
   {
       v.at(i) = v.at(i + 1);
       result.at(i) = v.at(i);
   }
   return result;
   // PUT CODE ABOVE THIS LINE. DON'T CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW.
}
```

All my teacher does it upload textbook pages that explain what certain parts of code are supposed to do but the textbook pages offer NO help in trying to figure out how to actually apply this stuff.

So could someone please give me a few pointers?

Comment: *but I don't think that will work given my code* -- That's very hard to believe if you are talking about `std::rotate` from `<algorithm>`.

Comment: It won't work, Paul. They're violating assignment rules if they add the `#include <algorithm>` outside the range of where they can make code modifications and if they try to put the include where they can make mods, Woooo! The compiler'll HATE that.

Comment: But for posterity, here's what the `std::rotate` solution could look like: https://ideone.com/FlAlT1

Comment: Side note: Reading books and documentation are vital to programming even when the documentation is cryptic as hell, and even the best seldom tells you exactly how to do what you want. Ultimately the only way to really learn to program is to program.

Comment: Thank you, for doing that code ^^. That also helped me understand how returning vectors work!
And yeah, reading programming documentation pages is extremely hard. So i've been watching videos, reading, and working with my classmates to figure out coding. (because the few uploaded textbook pages just don't cut it)

Answer (score 2):

Since you know exactly how many elements you have, and it's the smallest number that makes sense to rotate, you don't need to do anything fancy - just place the items in the order that you need, and return the result:

```
vector<int> rotate3(const vector<int>& x) {
    return vector<int> { x[1], x[2], x[0] };
}
```

Note that if your collection always has three elements, you could use `std::array` instead:

```
std::array<int,3>
```

Comment: Thank you! The fact that it required this little code and how much time I spent researching it, I wanna cry. We haven't covered arrays yet, but I'll keep that in mind!

Answer (score 1):

First, just pay attention that you have passed v as const reference (`const vector<int>&`) so you are forbbiden to modify the state of v in `v.at(i) = v.at(i + 1);`

Although Sergey has already answered a straight forward solution, you could correct your code like this:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> left_rotate(const vector<int>& v)
{
   vector<int> result;
   int size = v.size(); // this way you are able to rotate vectors of any size
   for (auto i = 1; i < size; ++i)
       result.push_back(v.at(i));

   // adding first element of v at end of result
   result.push_back(v.front());
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Sergey's answer. This answer deals with why what the asker attempted did not work. They're damn close, so it's worth going though it, explaining the problems, and showing how to fix it.

In

```
v.at(i) = v.at(i + 1);
```

`v` is `const`ant. You can't write to it. The naïve solution (which won't work) is to cut out the middle-man and write directly to the `result` `vector` because it is NOT `const`

```
result.at(i) = v.at(i + 1);
```

This doesn't work because

```
   vector<int> result;
```

defines an empty `vector`. There is no `at(i)` to write to, so `at` throws an exception that terminates the program.

As an aside, the `[]` operator does not check bounds like `at` does and will not throw an exception. This can lead you to thinking the program *worked* when instead it was writing to memory the `vector` did not own. This would *probably* crash the program, but it doesn't have to<sup>1</sup>.

The quick fix here is to ensure usable storage with

```
vector<int> result(v.size());
```

The resulting code

```cpp
vector<int> rotate(const vector<int>& v)
{
   // PUT CODE BELOW THIS LINE. DON'T CHANGE ANYTHING ABOVE.
   vector<int> result(v.size()); // change here to size the vector
   int size = 3;
   for (auto i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i)
   {
       result.at(i) = v.at(i + 1); // change here to directly assign to result
   }
   return result;
   // PUT CODE ABOVE THIS LINE. DON'T CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW.
}
```

almost works. But when we run it on {1, 2, 3} `result` holds {2, 3, 0} at the end. We lost the 1. That's because `v.at(i + 1)` never touches the first element of `v`. We could increase the number of for loop iterations and use the modulo operator

```cpp
vector<int> rotate(const vector<int>& v)
{
   // PUT CODE BELOW THIS LINE. DON'T CHANGE ANYTHING ABOVE.
   vector<int> result(v.size());
   int size = 3;
   for (auto i = 0; i < size; ++i) // change here to iterate size times
   {
       result.at(i) = v.at((i + 1) % size); // change here to make i + 1 wrap
   }
   return result;
   // PUT CODE ABOVE THIS LINE. DON'T CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW.
}
```

and now the output is {2, 3, 1}. But it's just as easy, and probably a bit faster, to just do what we were doing and tack on the missing element after the loop.

```cpp
vector<int> rotate(const vector<int>& v)
{
   // PUT CODE BELOW THIS LINE. DON'T CHANGE ANYTHING ABOVE.
   vector<int> result(v.size()); 
   int size = 3;
   for (auto i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i)
   {
       result.at(i) = v.at(i + 1);
   }
   result.at(size - 1) = v.at(0); // change here to store first element

   return result;
   // PUT CODE ABOVE THIS LINE. DON'T CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW.
}
```

Taking this a step further, the size of three is an unnecessary limitation for this function that I would get rid of and  since we're guaranteeing that we never go out of bounds in our for loop, we don't need the extra testing in `at`

```cpp
vector<int> rotate(const vector<int>& v)
{
   // PUT CODE BELOW THIS LINE. DON'T CHANGE ANYTHING ABOVE.
   if (v.empty()) // nothing to rotate.
   {
      return vector<int>{}; // return empty result
   }
   vector<int> result(v.size());
   for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; ++i) // Explicitly using size_t because
                                             // 0 is an int, and v.size() is an
                                             // unsigned integer of implementation-
                                             // defined size but cannot be larger
                                             // than size_t
                                             // note v.size() - 1 is only safe because
                                             // we made sure v is not empty above
                                             // otherwise 0 - 1 in unsigned math
                                             // Becomes a very, very large positive
                                             // number
   {
      result[i] = v[i + 1];
   }
   result.back() = v.front(); // using direct calls to front and back because it's 
                              // a little easier on my mind than math and [] 

   return result;
   // PUT CODE ABOVE THIS LINE. DON'T CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW.
}
```

We can go further still and use iterators and range-based `for` loops, but I think this is enough for now. Besides at the end of the day, you throw the function out completely and use `std::rotate` from the `<algorithm>` library.

<sup>1</sup>This is called [Undefined Behaviour (UB)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), and one of the most fearsome things about UB is anything could happen including giving you the expected result. We put up with UB because it makes for very fast, versatile programs. Validity checks are not made where you don't need them (along with where you did) unless the compiler and library writers decide to make those checks and give guaranteed behaviour like an error message and crash. Microsoft, for example, does exactly this in the `vector` implementation in the implementation used when you make a debug build. The release version of Microsoft's `vector` make no checks and assumes you wrote the code correctly and would prefer the executable to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> I saw the rotate() function, but I don't think that will work given my code.

Yes it will work.

When learning there is gain in "reinventing the wheel" (e.g. implementing rotate yourself) and there is also gain in learning how to use the existing pieces (e.g. use standard library algorithm functions).

Here is how you would use [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) from the standard library:

```
std::vector<int> rotate_1(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
   std::vector<int> result = v;
   std::rotate(result.begin(), result.begin() + 1, result.end());
   return result;
}
```